# How can I get last time this method was called in seconds?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, methods

Lets say I have this method:

```
void aaa()
{
    //code
    //code 
}
```

and this method:

```
void bbb()
{
    aaa();
}
```

I called `aaa()` two times, once in 10 seconds. I want a way for `aaa()` to tell that last time I have been called was 10 seconds ago. I'm using Unity so if there is something built in for such thing, that would be good.

Comment: I don't think Unity has a built-in function for that, you would have to keep track of that manually (e.g.: by creating a time stamp). But why exactly do you need to know when you last called a function? (Maybe there is an easier/better way to achieve what you want to do)

Comment: Simply store `DateTime.Now` in a variable and calculate the difference (`DateTime.Now - lastTimestamp`). The difference will be of Type `Timespan` and has a property `TotalSeconds`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to keep track of that yourself. So, store the last "time" you have been called in a variable somewhere, and use that the next time you've been called. And given that you're using Unity, you could use its [Time](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time.html) class. With a bit of pseudo-code, that could look like this:

```c#
float lastTimeCalled = 0.0f;

void aaa()
{
    if(lastTimeCalled > 0.0f)
    {
        Debug.Log(string.Format("Last time called was at {0} seconds", lastTimeCalled);
    }
    //code 

    lastTimeCalled = Time.realTimeSinceStartup;
}

void bbb()
{
    aaa();
}
```